I’ve defined a range name with formula LET, and I'm trying to reference this name from a cell using the INDIRECT formula but its not working
I’ve defined a range name with formula LET, and I'm trying to reference this name from a cell that contains this name. To do that im using the indirect formula but its not working.
When I replace the cell reference that contains the name that I defined with let, in this case the name is "quince", and insted of doing that I just hardcode the range $H$2:$H$7501 in the formula, it works fine.
It looks like my formula simply cant get the name from the cell and use the range that I defined with the let formula.
This is what I did:
 =LET(Sellers;$A$2:$A$7501;
diez;$G$2:$G$7501;
quince;$H$2:$H$7501;
veinte;$I$2:$I$7501;
veinticinco;$J$2:$J$7501;
treinta;$K$2:$K$7501;
treintaicinco;$L$2:$L$7501;
cuarenta;$M$2:$M$7501;
cuarentaicinco;$N$2:$N$7501;
SI.ERROR(FILAS(UNICOS(FILTRAR(
Sellers;
((INDIRECTO(AS3)>=AS4)*
($C$2:$C$7501>=$AS$2)
))));0))

The only important part is the definition I give to "quince":
quince;$H$2:$H$7501;
And that (INDIRECTO(AS3) is refering to cell "AS3" where I have written the word "quince".
I expected the excel tu read "quince" and understand that it has to replace "(INDIRECTO(AS3)" with $H$2:$H$7501.
Any Ideas of how I can repair this?


Are you required to use INDIRECT()?

Probably it is not working because Defined Names are scoped to workbook or worksheet while the named variable is scoped to the calculations defined within LET(). But I understand the use case here what you are trying to achieve.

=SI.ERROR(FILAS(UNICOS(FILTRAR($A$2:$A$7501;((INDICE($G$2:$N$7501;;COINCIDIR(AS3;{"diez";"quince";"veinte";"veinticinco";"treinta";"treintaicinco";"cuarenta";"cuarentaicinco"};0))>=AS4)*($C$2:$C$7501>=$AS$2)))));0)

@SpectralInstance your formula works great., thank you!

@bugdrown I thought Indirect would allow me to take the text from the cell as a text and not as a cell reference or value.
